# Numerous "truncate table dbo.MSreplication_monitordata" commands logged by distribution database

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

In doing a SQL Server audit, it was discovered that after hours last week, the distribution database started logging numerous "truncate table dbo.MSreplication_monitordata" commands. I can't seem to find which process(es) would initiate this command. Worse yet, the process seems to be tied to my login. In addition, during the same timeframe, the tempdb filled up its drive. Are there any replication gurus here who could help point me in the right direction as to what might be happening? It is transactional replication happening from a SQL 2014 box to a SQL 2016 box, and hasn't experienced issues before.

I have looked through the SQL logs, searched for processes which execute the "truncate table dbo.MSreplication_monitordata" command. I have checked the owner of the SQL Agent jobs related to replication.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal and to be expected when you open the Replication Monitor. Please refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

So basically, you left the Replication Monitor open. Once you close the Replication Monitor, the command will no longer execute in the background.